# Why logs say that "cannot read property push of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have a presentation in a bit and I think I will break my laptop.

I had this perfectly working code, and without changing anything I get this message.

Here is the piece of code where I get the error

```
 var array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < customerDetails.length; i++){
            array[i].push(customerDetails[i].name);
    }
```

btw customerDetails is an array of objects ie [{}, {}, {}]

How the heck is the array NOT defined? Initially I had the array definition in another place (outside the function so it was working fine and I moved it right in there just to test).

Either I am too tired and can't see it or there is another issue that actually results to it? the error itself does not make sense to me.

EDIT:
I put the answer from below here, there should be no array[i].push but instead array.push
Although I did not change that, I should still see it.
Thanks to this community for helping, you are really great!

Comment: Wht array[i].push ,array has array inside or what??

Comment: You never define `array[i]`, so you can't `push` to it, it's not an array

Comment: @AwadMaharoof - Probably not, given that `array.length` is `0` and so the body of hte loop would never run.

Comment: Why not just  `array = customerDetails.map(({ name }) => name)`?

Comment: If you have array and you want to push an object inside that array you shouldn't write array[i].push() - you should write array.push() 
array[i].push will use if you have an array of arrays.

Comment: Thank you all guys, indeed something was changed by another person and I couldn't see it because I have been up for hours. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

`push()` is a function related to `array`. You are pushing the value to an element of the array using `array[i].push()` which is not valid and not present. Push it directly to the `array` using  `array.push()`

```
var array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < customerDetails.length; i++){
            array.push(customerDetails[i].name);
    }
```

Comment: "You are pushing the value to an element of the array ... which is not valid" ... in _this case_. If `array = [[]]`, then `array[0].push(...)` would be perfectly valid.

Comment: @Vaggouras happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Use array.push instead of array[i].push

```
var array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < customerDetails.length; i++){
        array.push(customerDetails[i].name); // no need give array index while pushing data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < customerDetails.length; i++){
            array.push(customerDetails[i].name);
    }
```

You cannot use `array[i].push()` because it references a single element in array and not the array itself.